# what's the logic behinf the line num+=i>num

Tags: python, python-3.x

**This code print the number num=3  and wt's the logic behing this line num+=i>num**

```
num=0
for i in range(5,0,-1):
    num+=i>num
print(num
```

Comment: `>` returns `True` or `False`, which internally are `1` and `0` respectively, and can actually be treated as integers… Not that that makes this a good idea…

Comment: It's equivalent of `if i > num: num += 1`.

Comment: thank you @bereal for the answer

Answer (score 1):

For historical reasons, Python's `bool` is a subtype of `int`, `False == 0` and `True == 1`. This means you can add booleans to integers and get integers (in fact you can add booleans to booleans and get integers).

So `num+=i>num` is a pretty obfuscated (but potentially slightly more efficient) way to write:

```py
if i > num:
    num += 1
```